# NFourierTransform do not show all points, even change PlotPoints and Exclusions

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, fourier-analysis

```
Needs["FourierSeries`"]
```

I try solve the numerical Fourier transform  of this function:

```
E0[y_, a_] := -(1/54) E^((2 (1 - 3 a) Tanh[2 a y]^2)/(9 a))Cosh[2 a y]^(-6 - 4/(9 a)) 
    (-10 + 9 (11 - 34 a) a + 3 (-5 + 2 a) (-1 + 6 a) Cosh[4 a y] + (-6 - 3 a + 54 a^2) 
    Cosh[8 a y] + Cosh[12 a y])
```

where this E0 have the plot:

[image]

Then I use the NFourierTransform with two diferent methods, **Automatic** and **LocalAdaptive**:

```
F0[w_, a_] := NFourierTransform[E0[y, a], y, w, 
    Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]
```

In both cases the plot of this numerical Fourier tranform, `F0`, do not show all points, even if `Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 1000` were used, as can be see below:

```
Plot[F0[w, 0.05], {w, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> Full, 
    Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 1000, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

How to show the continuous points of these plots?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am uncertain in what version of Mathematica `NFourierTransform` occurs, but
`FourierTransform` works well in Mathematica 10.4 in Windows 64x.

```
F0[w_, a_] := FourierTransform[E0[y, a], y, w, 
    Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]
Plot[F0[w, 0.05], {w, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> Full, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Note that `Method` is an undocumented option of `FourierTransform`

It may be that the function `NFourierTransform` produces results with a small imaginary part.  If so, `Chop` the solution.

Addendum

My thanks to [J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) for pointing out in a comment below that `NFourierTransform` is a component of the FourierSeries package.  With the addition of

```
Needs["FourierSeries`"]
```

it can be combined with `Chop` to yield the desired plot, above.

```
F0[w_, a_] := Chop@NFourierTransform[E0[y, a], y, w, 
    Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]
```

Comment: `NFourierTransform[]` comes from loading ``<<FourierSeries`​``.

Comment: The Needs["FourierSeries`"] was already present in this question.

Comment: @bbgodfrey My Mathematica is v.10.0.0.0 working in a Windows 8 -64bits. In fact, the FourierTransform works well and faster fort this question, however, even that the   Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False} do not a valid option in this case.

Comment: @MelinaA.H  Yes, I noticed that Mathematica flags `Method` as not a valid option but nonetheless accepts and uses it.  This is not the first time I have seen such behavior.  Perhaps, `Method` is an undocumented experimental option.  By the way, ``Needs["FourierSeries`"]`` is not in your question.